# Is there another alternative to grep?

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have two `data frames`. One of them contains numbers of questions **as text** and I use the `grep()` function to match those numbers to the name of my other `dataframe` columns.

The problem is that a part of my `code` doesn't work because my `function` `grep()` is not doing the trick.

Basically my two `dataframes`are as follows

DF1:

| Question | Group |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | Redmeat |
| 100 | Chicken |
| 56 | Vegetables |
| 210 | Dairy |

DF 2 (values don't matter, only the column name):

| 1.Question | 2.Question | ... | 101.Question | ... | 250.Question |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | No | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| Yes | Yes | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| No | Yes | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| No | Yes | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I use the following code:

```
i <- n ## I change n according to the row of DF1 that I want
grep(DF1$Question[i], colnames(DF2), fixed = T)
```

If I do:

```
i <- 2  ## (Question number 100)
grep(DF1$Question[i], colnames(DF2), fixed = T)
```

My code returns 100, which is correct since it's the column that corresponds to "100.Question"

But if I do:

```
i <- 1  ## (Question number 1)
grep(DF1$Question[i], colnames(DF2), fixed = T)
```

My code returns 1, 11, 21 ... 101 ... 201

Same if i do:

```
i <- 3  ## (Question number 56)
grep(DF1$Question[i], colnames(DF2), fixed = T)
```

It returns 56, 156

I only want the exact same number. Even if i use the argument `fixed = TRUE` it doesn't work.

Is there a solution or an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options: 1) Include the `.` in the grep pattern, `grep(paste0("^", DF1$Question[i], "\\."), colnames(DF2))`, or 2) paste the full `".Question"` on and use exact matching without any grep at all: `paste0(DF1$Question, ".Question")`. This will likely be more efficient than regex. Since your code has these `i`s all over the place, I assume you're using a loop. grep and paste are vectorized, so if you provide more context we may be able to help you avoid the loop entirely.

Comment: In fact i use a loop but to create another dataframe and this grep( ) function problem crashes my loop. The problem is that I cannot include the whole name because they are very long questions, my example is very simplified. Nevertheless, the first option `grep(paste0("^", DF1$Question[i], "\\."), colnames(DF2))` seems to work! So thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What about specifying in the `pattern` that you want from the start `^` and you want it to be followed by `.Q`?

```
i=3
grep(paste0("^",DF1$Question[i],".Q"), colnames(DF2))
```

Output:

```
[1] 56
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `grep` for unique values, therefore you should `grep` the start of the string `^`, together with your number and the dot `.`. In this case, you cannot use the `fixed = T` argument, since you are using regex to match.

```
grep(paste0("^", DF1$Question[i], "\\."), colnames(DF2))
```